# object stocking in node.js

Tags: node.js

How can I create resuable blank objects in node.js? For example :
`In file1 :`

```
var Result = {
error :false,
errorReport :[]
}
exports.Result = Result;
```

`In file 2 :`

```
var result = require('../file1');
exports.doSomething  = function(){
var output = result.Result;
output.error = true;
output.errorReport = some_error_array;
}
```

Now, everytime I invoke doSomething(), it is obvious that the last `result` will be cached.
But, everytime I invoke doSomething(), i want a fresh object as it is declared in `Result` without any extra programming (i dont want to reset attributes everytime i do some thing with `Result` object.
Am I missing any minor detail here ? please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a class:

```
exports.Result = function() {
  this.error = false;
  this.errorReport = [];
};

// later on:
var output = new result.Result();
...
```

Or even make it fancy so that you can pass arguments:

```
exports.Result = function(error, errorReport) {
  this.error = error === undefined ? false : error;
  this.errorReport = errorReport === undefined ? [] : errorReport;
};

// later
var output = new result.Result(true, some_error_array);
```